# What graph system is the best for store transition graph with weights?

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, structure, networkx

I have the directed graph which structure is:

Nodes - name of some object in map, edges - is transition from 1 object to 2 object. Edges has a weight - count of transition (from statistics data)

Length of nodes about 2000
Length of edges about 50000

I need a fast function **find_path(name_object1, name_object2)** works with this large graph that returns a list of paths from object1 to object 2 with the biggest weigths.

So, my question is **what system should I use to reach best result (Neo4j, networkx ...?) what algorithm can be used for find all paths from huge graph with weighted edges?`**

Comment: `returns a list of paths from object1 to object 2 with the biggest weigths` 
you need all paths that have the biggest total weight?

Comment: @svs not all, maybe top 5-10 paths with the biggest total weight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, a graph with 2000 nodes in not a huge one.

Secondly, unlike the shortest path problem, [the longest path problem (weighted or not) is NP-hard in general case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem), so unless you graph has some special structure, you cannot hope for a polynomial solution.